# Laravel eager loading and LIKE filter

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am working with a typical Account->Zipcode scenario. I have 2 model2: Account and Zipcode, in Account I add

```
public function zipcode() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Zipcode::class);
}
```

The index.blade.php is like this:

```
<td>{{$account->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$account->fullname}}</td>
  <td>{{$account->address}}</td>
  <td>{{$account->zipcode->fulllocation}}</td>
...
```

I add a filter (basic input text on top of the list) for a string contained in **accounts.fullname** so the controller is like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
 {
   $search = $request->search;
   //The instructions in the closure given to when() will only be applied if the first argument is evaluated to true
   $accounts = Account::with('zipcode')//https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading
                  ->when($search,function ($query) use ($search) {
                     $query->where('fullname','like','%'.$search.'%');
                     return $query;
                    })
                  ->latest()
                  ->paginate(15);
     return view('accounts.index', compact('accounts'))->with('search',$search);
 }
```

At this point the scenario in tested and working, if no search is inserted all accounts are listed else the result is correctly filtered.

My need is to search the inserted string in **accounts.fullname** OR **accounts.zipcode.fulllocation**. I try to modifiy the *controller* in this way:

```
$accounts = Account::with('zipcode')//https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading
    ->when($search,function ($query) use ($search) {
              $query->where('fullname','like','%'.$search.'%');

              $query->orWhere('fulllocation','like','%'.$search.'%');//ADDED THIS

              return $query;
           })
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(15);
```

When I try it this error is raised:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fulllocation' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `accounts` where `fullname` like %foo% or `fulllocation` like %foo%)
```

Thanks to any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because the query is looking for `fulllocation` in the accounts table when it's actually in the `zipcodes` table.

You could try something like:

```
$query->where('fullname', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhereHas('zipcode', function ($q) use ($search) {
        $q->where('fulllocation', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is exactly what I need and what I am looking for. Actually I start configuring Account model based on MySql table and Zipcode model based on **Oracle** table. Appling your solution raise an error because the query do not find **mysqlschema.zipcode**. At this moment no need to be so complex so I move all on mysql and it work correctly (nothing change on Laravel side). I keep this case for further study.